# Why is "virtualenv venv" not working on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm having trouble creating a virtual environment for python on my Ubuntu desktop. I have installed virtualenv by: `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` and verifying it gives the following output:

```
$ pip3 show virtualenv
Name: virtualenv
Version: 15.1.0
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Ian Bicking
Author-email: ianb@colorstudy.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
```

However, when I try to create a virtual environment, I get one of these...

> Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install virtualenv

Why is that?

Comment: sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

For it to be run when you install it with `pip`, it does not put it into your path. You must use the following command to put a symlink to it in into /usr/local/bin

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

However this is not necessary as you can just install it from the repositories instead of using PyPi by

```
sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv && sudo apt-get install python3-virtualenv
```

Comment: I've pasted that command into the terminal and that gives me this....sudo: /usr/bin/easy_install: command not found

Comment: @NelsonKing Did you try the second command?

Comment: I've tried the second command but I'm still getting the Command 'virtualenv' not found message...

Comment: Can you add the output of `pip3 show virtualenv` to your question? @NelsonKing

Comment: @NelsonKing Answer updated.

Comment: That solved the issue but now I'm getting...bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: Permission denied
And I'm logged in as root. Perhaps it has sth to do with the fact that this is a VM so maybe I'l play around with the permissions.